# Missing "session stickiness" from ELB

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I'm new to AWS so I'm surely missing something basic but I've created a new ELB and I see no "Edit stickiness" configuration under the "Description" section of the ELB, as described [in this AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html) tutorial .

Any help will be appreciated,
thanks!

Comment: Which protocol are you using in the `Listeners`? Some protocols are not compatible with the stickiness (e.g. `Stickiness options not available for TCP protocols`) https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=721960

Comment: I have a single listener: "HTTP : 80" so I think this is not not issue :-/

Comment: You should have a button "Edit Stickiness" under the "Port configuration" section in the "Description" tab. Are you sure you are using an ELB and not an ALB?

Comment: Oh :( It was an Application LB and the configuration is totally different! Thanks @CélineAussourd so much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anyone stumbling across that - you are most likely using an "application load balancer" which means you need to [follow these steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#sticky-sessions) to enable stickiness.